# Block Chain Library

Tags: blockchain, library

I was wondering if there are any open source blockchain libs that I could use to build a project with?

UPDATED

I agree. With my knowledge of bitcoin now and blockchain - I should have phrased this question better.

What I am looking for is a pure blockchain implementation (lib) that can be used to implement anything I want on top of it, one implementation could be bitcoin.
This "blockchain 2.0" would not have the same limitations as blockchain today (hardcoded values, flexible message size, enhanced scripting language, etc..).

Lots of startups, companies, etc... implement their own blockchain because the bitcoins'version has been designed for bitcoin - it has not been designed to deal with other business problems.

Now I hope you see what I mean. But now I understand that I have to either do a hardfork of "bitcoin" and strip out "blockchain" - or I can try to find this "blockchain 2.0" that - for example - bitcoin could fork and be based on.

Do not be too quick to mark down. If it would be obvious, I would not ask for it ;-)

Comment: I'm unsure if you've researched this. Maybe specify a language to help get this moving, or what capabilities you need from the library.

Comment: Just basically a "blockchain" lib allowing me to send tx to a set of peer-to-peer nodes - visualising the chain - having a miner with a pluggable proof-of-work algo...  Might be too painful to find as opposed to re-write it knowing the concepts?

Comment: Actualy, as a language, ideally, in Java

Comment: I get why people are downvoting, but I've had an extraordinarily difficult time finding relevant Google hits... to the point where the library will dictate the language.  I wish people wouldn't be so downvote-happy and instead take the context of the question into account.

Answer (score 3):

Bitcoinj is based on Java and allows you to send transactions to the network. Its an implementation of the Bitcoin Protocol. However, it doesn't provide any way to visualize the blockchain (it only stores 646kb of the blockchain, not all 30gbs). You should improve the question to descrbe what exactly ou want to do!

Comment: I want to use blockchain without bitcoin. I can visualise the chain easily... Is the blockchain API (validation, pow, insertion, etc.) done in a way it can be extracted out from bitcoinj and used independently. Checking the source code....

Comment: I know bitcoinj - but I have edited my question. I could just strip out the blockchain implementation and expose it via services to be called by any implementer, one being bitcoin